# Here document gives EOF error in Ruby IO

Tags: ruby, string, io, eof

The following code give two errors which I am not able to resolve. Any help would be appreciated:

```
random.rb:10: can't find string "TEMPLATE" anywhere before EOF
random.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input
```

Code:

```
id = 2
File.open("#{id}.json","w") do |file|
file.write <<TEMPLATE
{
         "submitter":"#{hash["submitter"]}",
         "quote":"#{hash["quote"]}",
         "attribution":"#{hash["attribution"]}"
       }
       TEMPLATE
   end
```

Comment: what is `TEMPLATE` ? Have you defined it somewhere or you're simply copy pasting the code?

Comment: TEMPLATE is just placeholder for here document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents) (emphasis mine):

> The heredoc starts on the line following `<<HEREDOC` and **ends with the next line that starts with `HEREDOC`**

Your code doesn't contain a line starting with `TEMPLATE`. If your text editor (or IDE) supports regular expressions in searches, try `^TEMPLATE`.

You can either remove the spaces or if you want to keep them, change `<<TEMPLATE` into `<<-TEMPLATE`. The addition of `-` instructs the Ruby parser to search for an (possibly) intended `TEMPLATE` like you have in your code.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Code working fine after implementing the change.